# Node JS with Phantom JS to Scrape Dynamic Pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm a Java developer, but have played around with javascript very little. I am looking to develop a small Node JS app to parse a dynamic web page... so we need some way to wait until the page is fully loaded.  I managed to get a node js project running with a hello world app.

I then updated the project to support PhantomJS via the PhantomJS Node bridge (https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node).  I was able to successfully run one of their (PhantomJS Node bridge) samples in my node project (see below).  While this will successfully write the contents of the web page to a file, the content is not complete, as it does not contain the dynamic data (retrieved via javascript/AJAX).

Can someone tell me a code modification to the below that will allow it to wait until the page is fully loaded prior to writing the file?

** Edit - Just saw where another user has basically the exact same issue, but is unanswered:  [Dynamic scraping using nodejs and phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654763/dynamic-scraping-using-nodejs-and-phantomjs?rq=1)

Node js version 6.20, phantom js version 2.1.1, phantom js node (bridge) version 2.1.2

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var sitepage = null;
var phInstance = null;
phantom.create()
.then(instance => {
        phInstance = instance;
        return instance.createPage();
    })
.then(page => {
    sitepage = page;
    return page.open('http://www.somesite.com');
})
.then(status => {
    console.log(status);
    return sitepage.property('content');
})
.then(content => {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("output.html", content, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
    sitepage.close();
    phInstance.exit();
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    phInstance.exit(); 
});
```

Comment: This has been answered already here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17133526/2841139

Comment: Sorry, but neither of those answers address my issue.  One answer mentions to use the content property to retrieve the page (which the sample code does... only via the phantomjs-node bridge).  The other answer... using pscrape... from what I've researched, phantom should be able to do what I am asking without adding another library to the mix.

Comment: Perhaps you can adapt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21401636/1816580) to this bridge.